# php exception not working

Tags: php, exception

I have a simple program that should fire two exceptions, the second being a rethrow of the first. However, only the first exception is being thrown.

This is my code:

In dao.php

```
function executeSQLC($cn, $sql) {       
    $rs = odbc_exec($cn, $sql);
    if($rs == false) {
        throw new Exception("ex1: ".odbc_error());
    }

    return $rs;     
}
```

In bean.php

```
include("dao.php");

$conn = odbc_connect("xxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
odbc_autocommit($conn, FALSE);
$sql ="invalid sql";
try {
    executeSQLC($conn, $sql);
    odbc_commit($conn);
    odbc_close($conn);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    odbc_rollback($conn);
    throw new Exception("ex2: ".$e->getMessage(). " " .$sql);       
}
```

I see "ex1", so i think the first exception, at the dao, is being thrown, however, i can't see "ex2" and the connection never gets rollbacked.

Thanks

Comment: you see ex1 where? are you sure `executeSQLC` is not called somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe Exception2 i s not firing, because $sql is not in scope there

Comment: And `$sql` does not exist in `bean.php` maybe that will cause the throw to get upset with life

Comment: I just ran your code now, and both exceptions fire for me

Comment: Just a silly point: `executeSQLC()` returns data, so you should call it as `$something = executeSQLC($conn, "invalid sql");`

Comment: Do you use namespaces? The only case I can think of is that your try catch-block is a different/namespaced exception and that's why the other ex1 is not caught and rethrown

Comment: @RiggsFolly the lack of definition for $sql was a transcription mistake. I've corrected the body of the question to reflect reality. thanks

Comment: @dbrumann no, i do not use namespaces. i am a java developer and try to keep the use of php as simple as possible.

Comment: It's generally bad practice to throw and catch the root `Exception`. You should use a custom exception class that extends `Exception`. The danger of using `Exception` like this is that you will also catch any other exception that might be generated, and which you may not be expecting.

Comment: @Simba noted. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, some other code was calling/messing with the $sql variable, not sure that this was the cause, but things seem to be working now. Thanks folks.